# PHP 5.5 Excel-Object via COM/OLE cannot load file

Tags: php, excel, com, ole

**The Situation:** I am currently migrating an internal industry web application from Windows Server 2003/Apache 2.2/Php 5.3/Oracle 10 to Windows Server 2012/Apache 2.4/PHP 5.5/Oracle 12c.

The application uses the extension com_dotnet to use a server side installed excel  for special reports. I know that using excel on the server side is not the preferred way to work with sheets but it was once decided to do so because

- PHPExcel was not available or at least not powerful enough
- The reporting is never used by more than one person at a time

**The Problem in Detail:** PHP creates the Excel object OK:

```
 try {
      $excel = new COM("Excel.application");
      $excel->DisplayAlerts = 0;
      $excel->Visible = 0;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    ...
    }
```

But when I try to open a file I get an error:

```
 try {
        $excel->Workbooks->Open($fn);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        $excel->Quit();
        $excel = null;
        // ... Errormessage ...;
        return;
      }
```

The Error message (in $e) states that Excel could not find or open the requested file. While debugging with Netbeans I can see the excel instance appear in the Windows Task Manager.

**What I tried**:

- Made sure that the file in $fn can be opend. Changed file permission to "everyone" to no avail.
- Used / and \ in the path and tried to surround the path with ".

Unfortunately the installation is German, so is the error message:

Source: Microsoft Excel

Description: Microsoft Excel kann auf die Datei 'd:\apps\webroot\vebill\share\reports\Test.xls' nicht zugreifen. Dies kann mehrere Gründe haben:

- Der Name des Dokuments oder der Pfad ist nicht vorhanden.
- Das Dokument wird von einem anderen Programm verwendet.
- Der Name der Arbeitsmappe, die gespeichert werden soll, ist identisch zu dem Namen eines anderen Dokuments, welches schreibgeschützt ist.

None of those conditions is true.

Help is **very** appeciated! Thanks!

**What I forgot to mention** is that the old installation used Excel 2010, the new one uses Excel 2016.

**What I found out with Procmon**: As suggested I used procmon and filtered for EXCEL.EXE events. EXEL create file and open query information and all the following operations on the file have RESULT SUCCESS! Only one line may point to an error:

18:43:22,9966615
EXCEL.EXE
5916
CreateFileMapping
D:\apps\webroot\vebill\share\reports\Test.xls
FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS
SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection:

But later in the log the file is accessed again multiple times by Excel without any errors.

**Update 1**: I changed the login credentials of the Apache service to the admin user with which I am working - the error remains the same: Led Zeppelin alredy knew ;-)

**Update 2**: Found this SO issue, mine is a duplicate, unfortunately this is also not resolved. Will try to move to PHPExcel now...

[PHP fails to open an Excel workbook through COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194737/php-fails-to-open-an-excel-workbook-through-com)

Comment: `Description: Microsoft Excel can not access the file 'd: \ apps \ webroot \ vebill \ share \ reports \ test.xls'. This can have several reasons: The name of the document or the path does not exist. The document is used by another program. The name of the workbook that is to be saved is identical to the name of another document that is read-only.`
Did you check for all of this cases? Correct path (with double slash d:\\apps\\...), document opened..?

Comment: Use [`procmon`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to find out what's going on.

Comment: Yes, thats the exact translation of the error message I get and as I stated above, none of those cases is true. Also, I tried / and \\. The application works with forward slashes in the old environment.

Comment: Moved to PHPExcel,  was much more easy than expected. Missed only one Feature,  could solve it with a workaround...